# Does Response.RedirectPermanent automatically pass querystring variables?

Tags: query-string

I have googled to death this to no avail. I have a page that we no longer want to use, however, dpending on how it was called, I want to pass the querystring along if there is one. I wrote some ugly code to add the querystring if there is one, but if the Response.RedirectPermanent already does it then I could skip that step. The microsoft web site is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 301 redirect will redirect to whatever you pass into `RedirectPermanent`, exactly that. It will not re-append the curent query string to what you are redirecting to.